# Creating list of values with according to condition in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to create a list of jobs respecting precedence relationships stated by a dictionary.

```
 dict_preced = {(1, 2): 0,  (1, 3): 0,  (2, 1): 1,  (2, 3): 0,  (3, 1): 1,  (3, 2): 0}

 Where (j1, j2) == 1 means that j1 requires j2, 0 otherwise.
```

Supposing I already have starting list: `j_seq = [3, 2, 1]`, I need to create a `new_list` in which all values from j_seq will respect precedence relationship, meaning that there is no job being executed before a required job. (i.e., job 3 and job 2 cannot be executed before job 1).

Therefore, there are many candidate lists (i.e., `new_list = [1, 2, 3]` or `new_list = [1, 3, 2]`).
How to create samples of `new_list` that will always respect these precedence relationships?

I found many examples of list comprehension when each value need to respect a given condition with no dependences with other values. But I did not find any examples in which the condition stated concerns two values of the same list.

EDIT: I do not need to get all permutations respecting precedence constraints, just one is enough.

Comment: In the example you gave, 3 requires 2 and 2 requires 3. What do you consider the preference of relationships to be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to enumerate all the permutations of `j_seq`, and then do a lookup of each pair combination against your precedence dictionary to identify permutations that were invalid and could be thrown out.

For example:

```
import itertools

dict_preced = {(1, 2): 0,  (1, 3): 0,  (2, 1): 1,  (2, 3): 0,  (3, 1): 1,  (3, 2): 0}
j_seq = [3, 2, 1]
valid = []

for perm in itertools.permutations(j_seq):
    print('Permutation:', perm)
    for perm_pair in itertools.combinations(perm, 2):
        precedence = dict_preced.get(perm_pair, 0)
        print('\tCombination:', perm_pair, '=>', precedence)
        if precedence == 1:
            print('\tDecision: exclude', perm)
            break
    else:
        print('\tDecision: include', perm)
        valid.append(perm)

print('Result:', valid)
```

The result is: `[(1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3)]`.

The complete output (including debug logs) is:

```
Permutation: (3, 2, 1)
        Combination: (3, 2) => 0
        Combination: (3, 1) => 1
        Decision: exclude (3, 2, 1)
Permutation: (3, 1, 2)
        Combination: (3, 1) => 1
        Decision: exclude (3, 1, 2)
Permutation: (2, 3, 1)
        Combination: (2, 3) => 0
        Combination: (2, 1) => 1
        Decision: exclude (2, 3, 1)
Permutation: (2, 1, 3)
        Combination: (2, 1) => 1
        Decision: exclude (2, 1, 3)
Permutation: (1, 3, 2)
        Combination: (1, 3) => 0
        Combination: (1, 2) => 0
        Combination: (3, 2) => 0
        Decision: include (1, 3, 2)
Permutation: (1, 2, 3)
        Combination: (1, 2) => 0
        Combination: (1, 3) => 0
        Combination: (2, 3) => 0
        Decision: include (1, 2, 3)
Result: [(1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Hey, @jarmod many thanks for your help! It worked as needed for small examples. The problem is I am using lists with a len about 20. Therefore permutations lead me to hundreds of thousands of lists. It is impossible to process it in my PC

Comment: There is no need to calculate all permutations in my case because I just need to get one list that respects all precedence constraints. If you have an idea to get it without all permutations, please let me know. I apologize for not explaining this before

Comment: The itertools functions are generators afaik so are efficient. Would it suffice for you to simply terminate the search when you found the first valid permutation? Maybe turn this code into a function and instead of `valid.append(perm)` to accumulate all valid permutations, simply return the first one found using `return perm`?

Comment: I tried it but it is still very time_consuming. I am trying to adjust the precedence directly on the given  j_seq  but it is not working well. I tried to do: for p in test_list:
    i1 = test_list.index(p)     for el in test_list[i1:]:      i2 = test_list.index(el)    if dict_preced.get((el, p)) == 1:         test_list.remove(p)     test_list.insert(i2+1, p)   But it does not always work as needed. Would you have an idea in how to rectify it?

Comment: Do you have specific test case data that you can add to your question, along with your current code, and explain what the problem is (if too slow, how slow is it? if it's failing, how does it fail?)

Comment: Finally, I used a constraint programming optimization to get all feasible sequences and it worked. Besides more than 10^13 permutations, only about a hundred of them are valid, so I guess that CPO is the better option in this case. Many thanks anyway for your time and help!

Comment: Can you elaborate? It might help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question because I found a solution to this problem.

When using short length lists, the method proposed by @jarmod can be handy. However, when long lists are considered, it becomes impracticable to use his method because the number of permutations arises to 10^18.

For those having access to the CP optimizer from IBM CPLEX (or other constraint programming solver), a possible alternative is using the constraint propagation method to obtain some lists of valid sequences (respecting the precedence constraints).

In my case, I called the CP optimizer through the docplex module.
You can check out the script here: https://github.com/campioni1/CPO_Docplex_precedence_constraints

Please, let me know if you encounter any difficulties,